# React router:I don't want user to directly navigate to pages by typing urls but allow going to pages only using links inside the app.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

My Routes.js

```
<Route path="/game-center" component={GameCenter} />
      <Route path="/game-center/pickAndWin" component={PickAndWin} />
      <Route path="/game-center/memory" component={Memory} />
      <Route path="/game-center/summary" component={GameSummary} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

On Card Click i'm routing him to the game or summary depending whther game is live or expired.

```
cardClick=(type, name, status, gameId) => {
    console.log(`here${type}${status}`, name);
    this.props.dispatch(GameCenterActions.setShowGame());
    if (status === LIVE) {
      this.props.dispatch(GameCenterActions.selectGame({ type, name, status, gameId }));
      this.props.dispatch(GameCenterActions.resetShowSummary());
      hashHistory.push(LIVE_GAMES[type]);
    } else if (status === EXPIRED) {
      this.props.dispatch(GameCenterActions.setShowSummary());
      console.log(`${EXPIRED_GAMES}summary page here`);
      this.props.dispatch(GameCenterActions.selectGame({ type, name, status, gameId }));
      hashHistory.push('/game-center/summary');
    }
  }
```

When user directly types url '/game-center/summary' he should not be allowed and should be sent back to home page. 
Is this possible in react router itself? I want to implement this in my entire app. 
I don't want user to directly navigate to pages by typing urls but going to pages only using links inside the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using Higher Order Components.
Such as you can set a flag when user is authenticated and then attach this HOC with the specified component in react router

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
export default function(ComposedComponent){
  class Authentication extends Component{
    static contextTypes = {
      router : React.PropTypes.object
    }
    componentWillMount(){
      if(!this.props.user){
        this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps){
      if(!nextProps.user){
          this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }
    render(){
      return(<ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>);
    }
  } 
}
```

And then in your routes

```
  <Route path="home" component={requireAuth(Home)}></Route>
```

Comment: I do not care about authentication. Game-center component has cards by clicking on which i can go to '/sumary' or the game itself. I don't want user to directly type '/game-center/summary' in url and go to summary page.

Comment: You can actually customize the above code in such a way that when user tries to visit the page directly he is kicked back to the home page.As
`this.context.router.push('/')`

Comment: I'm not sure what will i put as conditions in above code?
I want to make sure he has visited game-center and has clicked on button which changes route to summary. if he has directly typed url '/game-center/summary' he should be redirected to home. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: You can simple set a `flag` to `true` if the game-center is clicked.And later in the HOC check if the `flag` is `true` only then let the user pass else kick him back to homepage.

Comment: Hey! I guess i got what you were saying. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: The question is not related to auth, is related to know in react-router if its first load.