# Can I block navigating to a view by url but still allow routing programmatically?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

To summarize I still want to allow a user to click a button and be taken to a view that is in our react router like how it works today. However, I never want the user to be allowed to navigate to this view by url in their web browser. Just want to permanently block that for that specific view. Is there any simple ideas for pulling this off without having to work with local storage?

I saw a similar question here but it is asking for the whole application when I just want it this way for one specific view. The answer also seems to involve authentication. [React router:I don't want user to directly navigate to pages by typing urls but allow going to pages only using links inside the app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836337/react-routeri-dont-want-user-to-directly-navigate-to-pages-by-typing-urls-but)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add these special `<Route/>` when your app is fully loaded or with a specific action. If routes don't exist on first load or without a specific action, he can't reach these routes with the url.

Comment: So just dynamically create the route on click and send them there? Would that still allow the user to refresh the view once they are there with the browser? I would not want them to be able to do that still.

Comment: If you create them dynamically, when he refresh, he's loading a new fresh app, without those routes created dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the routing to boostrap up at the start of the application due to all the providers I have wrapped around it. Logging, redux, etc. Thanks for your suggestion though. I was able to solve the problem by using a location.state property in the react redirect component.